# импорт классов-наследников

Tags: java, импорт

Как получить доступ к классу из другого пакета?
То есть: в пакете *packageА* есть класс *Class1* и класс *Class2 extends Class1*
В пакете *packageB* у меня получается заимпортировать только класс *Class1*.

Comment: Сделайте класс `Class2` `public`.

Comment: А что происходит при импорте `Class2`? Укажите сообщения об ошибках, а лучше постройте [показательный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: разобрался, класс действительно должен быть public. а public он может быть только как отдельный файл *.java. 
Спасибо.